# Average Group size per month Over previous ten years

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

I need to find the average size (average number of employees) of all the groups (employers) that we do business with per month for the last ten years.

So I have no problem getting the average group size for each month. For the Current month I can use the following:

```
Select count(*)
from Employees EE
join Employers ER on EE.employerid = ER.employerid
group by ER.EmployerName
```

This will give me a list of how many employees are in each group. I can then copy and paste the column into excel get the average for the current month.

For the previous month, I want exclude any employees that were added after that month. I have a query for this too:

```
Select count(*)
from Employees EE
join Employers ER on EE.employerid = ER.employerid 
where EE.dateadded <= DATEADD(month, -1,GETDATE())
group by ER.EmployerName
```

That will exclude all employees that were added this month. I can continue to this all the way back ten years, but I know there is a better way to do this. I have no problem running this query 120 times, copying and pasting the results into excel to compute the average. However, I'd rather learn a more efficient way to do this.

Another Question, I can't do the following, anyone know a way around it:

```
Select avg(count(*))
```

Thanks in advance guys!!

Edit: Employees that have been terminated can be found like this. NULL are employees that are currently employed.

```
Select count(*)
from Employees EE
join Employers ER on EE.employerid = ER.employerid
join Gen_Info gne on gne.id = EE.newuserid
where EE.dateadded <= DATEADD(month, -1,GETDATE())
and (gne.TerminationDate is NULL OR gen.TerminationDate < DATEADD(day, -14,GETDATE())
group by ER.EmployerName
```

Comment: I really hope you don't have to do this in mySQL, oracle, and SQL server... which is it as the date logic for each is different.  Also some sample data with expected results would help frame the question better.

Comment: syntax looks for mssql

Comment: what about Employees that Leave an Employer?  You show us how to determine when they are added but not how to recognize when they are removed.  If they leave and they are no longer in the Employees Table then you can never have an accurate average because you would never count employees that were at one time employed

Comment: I'm with Matt here. With the data given so far you simply cannot determine how many employees worked at a time for an employer.

Comment: Edited my original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you after a query that shows the count by year and month they were added?  if so this seems pretty straight forward.

this is using mySQL date functions Year & month.

```
Select AVG(cnt) FROM (
  Select count(*) cnt, Year(dateAdded), Month(dateAdded)
  from System_Users su
  join system_Employers se on se.employerid = su.employerid 
  group by Year(dateAdded), Month(dateAdded)) B
```

The inner query counts and breaks out the counts by year and month  We then wrap that in a query to show the avg.

--2nd attempt but I'm Brain FriDay'd out.

This uses a Common table Expression (CTE) to generate a set of data for the count by Year, Month of the employees, and then averages out by month.
if this isn't what your after, sample data w/ expected results would help better frame the question and I can making assumptions about what you need/want.

```
With CTE AS (
Select Year(dateAdded) YR , Month(DateAdded) MO, count(*) over (partition by Year(dateAdded), Month(dateAdded) order by DateAdded Asc) as RunningTotal
from System_Users su
join system_Employers se on se.employerid = su.employerid 
Order by YR ASC, MO ASC)
Select avg(RunningTotal), mo from cte;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm not looking to count by when an employee was added. Rather I need to find the average group size per month all the way back to 2006.

Comment: So this sounds like you need a running "Average"  by month/year which might be doable by an analytic...

Comment: I don't think a 'running average' is exactly what I'm looking for. When computing the running average and new a value is added, the oldest value is dropped. 

For example, the moving average of six-month sales may be computed by taking the average of sales from January to June, then the average of sales from February to July, then of March to August, and so on

For example,  the running average of 6 month sales can be computed by taking the average sale from Jan to June, then the averages from Feb to July. I do not want to drop any data, the way the Jan was dropped in my example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I highly appreciate it.
Your second attempt is extremely close to what I'm looking for. However, dateadded needs to removed from the query, I was using the dateadded column to avoid counting employees past a certain date. I've been playing with it, but I don't know how to get the month/year going back 2006. I would need the results like this

For example, I would use the dateadded column to avoid counting employees that were added after october 31 to get my average group size in october.